# Error netfx.x86$IdentityHost failed to start while launching vs ide

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am getting this error and it is really annoying.

I can't use visual studio ide because of it.

I have tried updating vs22.

I have tried using the repair option. (twice)

I have tried reinstalling vs22.

Nothing worked.

And I tried searching for a solution online, it seems I am the only one facing this problem.

I have used vs22 for more than 3months now, and this error only showed up like last week.

I don't know how to provide more information about this error, if I missed anything please let me know.

I would appreciate any suggestion!

```
Could not start visual studio due to an error.
StreamJsonRpcRemotelnvocationException: 
Failed to start host 'netfx.x86$identityHost'. Host exited with exit code '-532462766'. (Errorkind: HostExited HResult: 80131500)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssZce.png)

Comment: Assuming it could be some damaged Windows local-user-profile part, I'd probably try creating a new local Windows account if possible, name it "BroIsBegging2" or similar, and then hope to start VS successfully as the new Windows user

Comment: @StefanWuebbe I have the same problem and i tried your suggestion, it still gives the same error

Comment: @FunnyBunny , does the `/SafeMode` option help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022

Comment: ... and does it depend on opening VS with a particular solution *.sln or not?

Comment: sorry for late response, it doesnt open at all, not with .sln not with the vs installer launch option, like it doesnt open at all

Comment: @StefanWuebbe forgot to tag you in the my previous comment

Comment: about the safemode, i havent tried it yet, i am not home, when i get home i will try it for sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248117/discussion-between-funny-bunny-and-stefan-wuebbe).

Comment: FWIW, "StreamJsonRpcRemotelnvocationException" in the OP's Error quote looks like a typo to me, might perhaps rather be "StreamJsonRpcRemoteinvocationException" with an "i" in the middle instead of the `"L".ToLower()`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and checked the logs.
There was a machine.config misconfiguration, in my case it was related to an Oracle driver.
I'm using a windows machine and found the logs for these at "%temp%\servicehub\logs".